# MTASA GTA SA On Ubuntu Keeps Crashign

Tags: 14.04

I installed GTA and it works completly fine. I have samp and it works. I tried installing MTA and it turns on...But then it just closes. Any fixes?

Comment: It is hard to understand what this question is or was about and **the answer isn't really helpful either**. I assume it's about a game from the GTA franchise not natively running on Linux and MTA probably stands for Multi Theft Auto, not Mail Transfer Agent. Overuse of acronyms without explanation or context doesn't really help when seeking for help. **Voting to close** with unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yea im speaking of multi theft auto...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing some essential programs if you haven't.. C++ 2005/2008 Redistributable Package and perhaps .NET 2/3/3.5. That could be the problem. If that doesn't work, then I am not sure.. Never used MTA so can't help you there too. SAMP works great though :D

Comment: Finally...Just moved back to windows.

Comment: Thats nice to hear!